# MassTransit + azure service bus consuming custom type messages

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, masstransit

I try to consume custome type message by my MassTransit service that subscribes to a azure service bus topic.

The messages has custom type and data of message stored is in custom properties. Here is an image of message from azure service bus explorer:

[image]

When trying to consume this I got :

[image]

MassTransit does not recognizes custom type unless it is in message header :/

Is there any way to configure endpoint so it can consume this type of message ?

Answer (score 0):

Without a `ContentType` to differentiate the message serialization from the formats supported by MassTransit, there isn't currently a way to change it. And *blank* or *null* is not a valid content type, so that cannot be used to select it.

You would need to either add a content type, or change the message format at this point. You could submit an issue and if somebody gets around to making it possible to add an empty or unsupported serializer.